# How to set image, description and title for like, comment, send in cakephp facebook plugin?

Tags: facebook, cakephp, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I’m using webtechnick cakephp facebook plugin. I want to set image description and title for like send and comments. There are many like and send in one page. Current site get same title(what in the title tag in the html ) . i want to set different titles and descriptions for each like and send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to set different titles and descriptions for each like and send.

Then have them point to *different* URLs, and set up a HTML page under each of those that contains the appropriate OG meta tags.

Comment: Check the http://techcrunch.com/ 
There are many like buttons in same page for each post.
i want to implement that kind of think

Comment: Check my answer. I already told you how it’s done. If you already have separate article pages with the appropriate OG meta tags in them, then you just have to set their URLs when embedding the like buttons.